# Exchangelib: How to iterate over all emails in a folder

Tags: python, exchangelib

I need to iterate all emails in a folder, eventually exporting to CSV format. Here's the important bits of code:

```
credentials = ServiceAccount(user, password)
...
qs = account.inbox.all()
qs.page_size = 100
qs.order_by('-datetime_received')
emails = qs.iterator()
for i, email in enumerate(emails):
    print(i, email.subject, email.sender, email.datetime_received)
```

When I run, I get an error every time, but not at the same point in the process. 
 Sometimes I get one page back (i == 99), sometimes I get three pages back (i==299) or five pages back (i==499).  Five pages are the most I've gotten back.  No matter where the error occurs, it's this error.  FWIW, the error does happen at page breaks.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "outlook.py", line 81, in <module>
    for i, email in enumerate(emails):
  File "C:\dev\programs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\queryset.py", line 390, in _as_items
    for i in iterable:
  File "C:\dev\programs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\account.py", line 628, in fetch
    shape=IdOnly,
  File "C:\dev\programs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services.py", line 602, in _pool_requests
    for elem in r.get():
  File "C:\dev\programs\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 644, in get
    raise self._value
  File "C:\dev\programs\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "C:\dev\programs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services.py", line 591, in <lambda>
    lambda c: self._get_elements(payload=payload_func(c, **kwargs)),
  File "C:\dev\programs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services.py", line 90, in _get_elements
    response = self._get_response_xml(payload=payload)
  File "C:\dev\programs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services.py", line 174, in _get_response_xml
    res = self._get_soap_payload(soap_response=soap_response_payload)
  File "C:\dev\programs\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\exchangelib\services.py", line 229, in _get_soap_payload
    raise SOAPError('Unknown SOAP response: %s' % xml_to_str(body))
exchangelib.errors.SOAPError: Unknown SOAP response: <ns0:Body xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
```

Is this the correct approach to walking through all emails?  What does this error mean and how do I fix it?  Thanks!

UPDATE:
Following is the captured output.  We don't see anything that looks like a 'backoff' message.  Does this help you identify any issues?

```
<< This run had page size set to 10 >>
DEBUG:exchangelib.util:Session 5122 thread 9556: Useful response from https://our.host.name/EWS/Exchange.asmx
DEBUG:exchangelib.protocol:Server our.host.name: Releasing session 5122
DEBUG:exchangelib.services:Trying API version Exchange2010_SP2 for account myaccount@myhost.com
DEBUG:exchangelib.services:FindItem: Got page with next offset 360 (last_page False)
DEBUG:exchangelib.services:Starting GetItem._get_elements worker 36 for 10 items
DEBUG:exchangelib.services:GetItem._get_elements result 30 is ready early

<< 10 of these DEBUG lines come out >>
DEBUG:exchangelib.services:Getting item ('AAMkADJjMDIwNmQwLWQ2NzYtNDk5OC04MjgxLT
MzZTdhMTk4YWRiNQBGAAAAAABGQ9HU4LA/RY8Mwwr5Jp5OBwDOJO2TCOmBSZeM4xH+g3x5AAAAiE7BAA
DOJO2TCOmBSZeM4xH+g3x5AAAe2nAfAAA=', 'CQAAABYAAADOJO2TCOmBSZeM4xH+g3x5AAAe2wDA')

DEBUG:exchangelib.services:Getting item ('AAMkADJjMDIwNmQwLWQ2NzYtNDk5OC04MjgxLT
MzZTdhMTk4YWRiNQBGAAAAAABGQ9HU4LA/RY8Mwwr5Jp5OBwDOJO2TCOmBSZeM4xH+g3x5AAAAiE7BAA
DOJO2TCOmBSZeM4xH+g3x5AAAe2nAeAAA=', 'CQAAABYAAADOJO2TCOmBSZeM4xH+g3x5AAAe2wC+')  

...

<<Seemed to process the above page successfully, then starts w/ errors >>
File "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 502, in read_chunked
DEBUG:exchangelib.protocol:Server our.host.name: Waiting for session
DEBUG:exchangelib.protocol:Server our.host.name: Got session 5122
DEBUG:exchangelib.util:Session 5122 thread 6408: retry 0 timeout 120000 
    POST'ing to https://our.host.name/EWS/Exchange.asmx after 1000s wait self._update_chunk_length()
File "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 448, in _update_chunk_length
    line = self._fp.fp.readline()
  File "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py", line 575, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 929, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 791, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
  File "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\ssl.py", line 575, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 676, in generate
    for chunk in self.raw.stream(chunk_size, decode_content=True):
  File "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 353, in stream
    for line in self.read_chunked(amt, decode_content=decode_content):
  File "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 530, in read_chunked
    self._original_response.close()
  File "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 77, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\response.py", line 250, in _error_catcher
    raise ProtocolError('Connection broken: %r' % e, e)
requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ("Connection broken: 
    ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)", 
    ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "email_test.py", line 27, in <module>
    for i, email in enumerate(emails):
  File "%WORKSPACE%\nlp\exchangelib\exchangelib\queryset.py", line 390, in _as_items
    for i in iterable:
  File "%WORKSPACE%\nlp\exchangelib\exchangelib\account.py", line 628, in fetch
    shape=IdOnly,
  File "%WORKSPACE%\nlp\exchangelib\exchangelib\services.py", line 596, in _pool_requests
    for elem in r.get():
  File "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 608, in get
    raise self._value
  File "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "%WORKSPACE%\nlp\exchangelib\exchangelib\services.py", line 585, in <lambda>
    lambda c: self._get_elements(payload=payload_func(c, **kwargs)),
  File "%WORKSPACE%\nlp\exchangelib\exchangelib\services.py", line 89, in _get_elements
    response = self._get_response_xml(payload=payload)
  File "%WORKSPACE%\nlp\exchangelib\exchangelib\services.py", line 163, in _get_response_xml
    allow_redirects=False)
  File "%WORKSPACE%\nlp\exchangelib\exchangelib\util.py", line 547, in post_ratelimited
    _raise_response_errors(r, protocol, log_msg, log_vals)  # Always raises an exception
  File "%WORKSPACE%\nlp\exchangelib\exchangelib\util.py", line 603, in _raise_response_errors
    raise r.headers['TimeoutException']
  File "%WORKSPACE%\nlp\exchangelib\exchangelib\util.py", line 494, in post_ratelimited
    r = session.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=data, allow_redirects=False, timeout=protocol.TIMEOUT)
  File "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 522, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 628, in send
    r.content
  File "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 755, in content
    self._content = bytes().join(self.iter_content(CONTENT_CHUNK_SIZE)) or bytes()
  File "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 679, in generate
    raise ChunkedEncodingError(e)
requests.exceptions.ChunkedEncodingError: ("Connection broken: 
    ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)", 
    ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))
```

Comment: That's a bug - there's nothing wrong with your example except that `qs.order_by()` is ignored because `order_by()` returns a copy of the query instead of modifying the original. Which version of exchangelib is this? Can you capture the XML of the request and response that fails, as described in https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib#troubleshooting, and open an issue at https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/issues?

Comment: Thanks for the input.  The version is 1.11.3.  We have turned on the debug logging, and have seen a message similar to 'existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', which makes me think the issue is with our firewall or Exchange server configuration.  We are looking into that now, but if that turns out not to be the issue I'll capture the XML and do as you suggest.

I have been able to sort of brute force get past the issue by catching the error, sleeping for a bit, then trying again.

Comment: Ok. It may be interesting to look at the request and response leading up to the error. It could be that the server is sending a request to backoff which exchangelib ignores, and the server then forcibly closes the connection.

Comment: Updated the question with the captured output.  Does that help?

Comment: I opened an issue on github as requested, and their recommended patch solved the issue.
https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/issues/423